# Ubuntu installation stop at "grub-install"

Tags: partitioning, grub2

I have tried to install Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, but met the same error.
When installing stock at "grub-install", the whole system is not responding, mouse and keyboard can not use.
[image]

The PC to install Ubuntu is HP Z2 G4 Workstation. Only one SSD disk is connected, i want to install only Ubuntu.
Cause i have tried several times, the last time, i following carefully with this manual [partition creation procedure](https://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu?newreg=c0663bfd282c427f908d34beda08648f). But doesn't work either.
I create bootable usb stick with rufus, tried both GPT/MBR partition schema.

I have before successful installed the Ubuntu 16.04 on the same machine, same disk.

What is the solution, thanks.